# Mark applications in your message box as read if viewed via job listing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I have built up 266 unread messages over the last year or so, but I have reviewed the candidates via the manage candidates view on the job listing.

I would be great if viewing a candidate marked their corresponding message as read.

Comment: This is slightly more complicated than that because there is a messages tab on the candidate popup, but in the case of applications we can certainly set the application as read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just pushed to production. When you view a candidate in the candidate manager we will mark the application (if any) as read.

Also, opening the messages tab of the candidate it will mark those messages as read too (although it always did that).

Comment: Good stuff, although I do have now 340+ unread messages - a select all (not just the ones one the page) would be amazing - or could someone manually just clear my mailbox out?